# Unexpected Seasonal Pattern when Comparing Empirical Probability with Hoeffding's Inequality

Tags: probability-inequalities, multiarmed-bandit, hoeffdings-inequality

I am visualizing the difference between the empirical probability and the theoretical upper bound of the deviation of the sample mean from the true mean of successive Bernoulli trials. I'm using Hoeffding's inequality for this comparison. However, I've noticed an unexpected seasonal pattern in my empirical bound. I'm trying to understand whether this pattern arises due to an error in my code or logic, or if it's a known phenomenon:

[image: Plot of empirical vs theoretical bounds]

Can anyone explain the observed pattern? Or have I made an error in my calculations?

Here's the code I used:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num_tosses = 500
num_experiments = 1000
mean = 0.5
hoeffding_eps = 0.05

tosses = []
for experiment in range(num_experiments):
    _tosses = []
    
    for toss in range(num_tosses):
        sample = np.random.binomial(1, mean, 1)[0]
        _tosses.append(sample)
        
    tosses.append(_tosses)
    
tosses = np.array(tosses)

# Here, I obtain the empircal mean for every step and each experiment. 
cum_mean = tosses.cumsum(axis=1)/np.arange(1, 1+tosses.shape[1])


def hoeffding_ineq(eps, n, a, b):
    return 2*np.exp(-(2*n*eps**2)/(b-a)**2)

hoef = [hoeffding_ineq(hoeffding_eps, i, 0, 1) for i in range(1, 1+num_tosses)]

empirical_probability_bound = (np.abs(cum_mean - mean) > hoeffding_eps).mean(axis=0)
plt.plot(empirical_probability_bound, label="Empirical Bound")
plt.plot(hoef, label="Theorical Bound")
plt.xlim(0, 200)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: It seems that this lecture note from the University of Massachusetts Amherst also shows the pattern:
https://people.cs.umass.edu/~domke/courses/sml2010/10theory.pdf